# How can I build mongoose in the browser with webpack?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

Our app uses mongoose (v4.6.5) in the browser(http://mongoosejs.com/docs/browser.html) but I have recently switched over to using webpack (v2.1.0-beta.27) and webpack-dev-server (for development: v(2.1.0-beta.11) to run our builds and it's having trouble parsing mongoose.

When it tries, it gets this error:

```
WARNING in ./~/mongoose/lib/drivers/index.js
8:11 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

I went to that file and saw that it tries to import a binary file if `window` is undefined:

```js
/*!
 * ignore
 */

var driver;

if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  driver = require(global.MONGOOSE_DRIVER_PATH || './node-mongodb-native');
} else {
  driver = require('./browser');
}

/*!
 * ignore
 */

module.exports = driver;
```

I'm guessing mongoose in the browser does NOT want to read from the binary file which is the point of this check. The problem is that `window` doesn't exist at the point of compilation since it's being compiled by webpack, so it also attempts to statically analyze this binary file.

I tried adding this to the mongoose file to prevent webpack from proceeding down mongoose's server-side dependency graph:

```js
/*!
 * ignore
 */

var driver;

if (typeof window === 'undefined' && process.env.BUILD_ENV !== 'browser') {
  driver = require(global.MONGOOSE_DRIVER_PATH || './node-mongodb-native');
} else {
  driver = require('./browser');
}

/*!
 * ignore
 */

module.exports = driver;
```

I then run my webpack build with `env BUILD_ENV=browser webpack-dev-server` but it doesn't work, I'm guessing because webpack doesn't actually execute your code but statically analyzes it.

I saw this PR on mongoose as well but it doesn't seem to have fixed my issue: `https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/4512/files`.

My question then is how can I use mongoose in the browser (with webpack) without having it read from the binary file?

Comment: having the same issue. any luck?